# How is the spectral decomposition of a skew-symmetric matrix $A$ related to that of $iA$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, skew-symmetric-matrices

Any skew-symmetric matrix can be written as $A=UQU^\dagger$ where $U$ is unitary and
\begin{align*}
Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & \lambda_1 &  \\
    -\lambda_1 & 0 &  \\
     &  & 0 & \lambda_2\\
     &  & -\lambda_2 &0\\
     &  &  &  & \ddots\\
     &  &  &  &  & 0 & \lambda_r\\
     &  &  &  &  & -\lambda_r & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix#Spectral_theory)

Moreover $\{\lambda_i\}$ are the eigenvalues of $iA$.

If $V$ diagonalizes the hermitian matrix $iA=VDV^\dagger$, what is the relation between $U$ and $V$ ?

Comment: Note that this only applies to skew-symmetric matrices with real entries or skew-Hermitian matrices. The page you link is referring to matrices with real entries.

Comment: Regarding your question, you can simply take $U = V$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann $U\neq V$, otherwise $Q$ would be equal to $iD$

Comment: Right, and $Q$ is not diagonal in this case... my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that there are multiple matrices satisfying the properties of the desired matrix $V$, so it doesn't make sense to talk about "the" matrix that diagonalizes $iA$. However, with the following hint, we can use $U$ to generate one such matrix $V$.

**Hint:** Let $J,K$ denote the matrices
$$
J = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&i\\i&1}, \quad K = \pmatrix{J\\ & \ddots \\ & &J},
$$
where $K$ has the same shape as $Q$. We find that $K$ is unitary and that $K^\dagger QK$ is diagonal.

Comment: right, now $V=KU$. thanks